# Testing AngularJS controllers using expectPOST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, jasmine

I've got a AngularJS/Rails app and I want to test my AngularJS controller is posting to the backend server when creating a new record. (I'm using jasmine for my tests)

Here is my attempted test

```
  describe "create", ->
    beforeEach(inject ( ($controller, $rootScope, $location, $state, $httpBackend) ->
      @redirect = spyOn($location, 'path')
      @httpBackend.whenGET('/assets/layouts/default.html.erb').respond(200)
      @httpBackend.whenGET('/assets/letters/index.html.erb').respond(200)
      @httpBackend.whenPOST('/api/letters').respond(200)

      $controller("LettersController", { $scope: @scope, $location: @location })
    ))

    it "sends a post to the backend", ->
      @httpBackend.expectPOST('/api/letters', {"letter":{},"_utf8":"☃"}).respond(200)
      @scope.create()
```

Here s the code which I'm testing:

```
  $scope.create = ->
    Letter.save(
      {}
    ,
      letter:
        subject: $scope.letter.subject
        body: $scope.letter.body

    # success
    , (response) ->
      $location.path "/letters"
    # failure
    , (response) ->
    )
```

The code in question works correctly and the test passes. The problem is if I comment my Letter.save code out (which makes the post through AngularJS resources) then my test still passes.

How can I get my test to work properly?

My full test application is here: https://github.com/map7/angularjs_rails_example2

Answer (score 2):

You need to verify that there are no outstanding requests at the end of your tests:

```
$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
```

Comment: After adding this line to my test and remarking out the 'Letter.save' the test still passes when it should fail.

Comment: Something is missing.  I do this type of thing all the time. That line should throw if you expect something that didn't get requested. Where are you adding `verifyNoOutstandingRequest`?

Comment: The only difference that I can think of, is that I also call `$httpBackend.flush()` after the function that requests the data, but all that should do is cause the callbacks to get called.  It shouldn't affect the outstanding requests...

Comment: I've tried adding verifyNoOutstandingRequest at every point in my test under the 'it' line and I've tried putting flush after the function. When putting the flush after it complains that it has nothing to flush, but nothing about the expectPOST line.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to verify that there are no outstanding expectations with `$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation`

This should prevent you from getting false positives I believe.

Also, I'm not sure that your expectPOST should return true because you don't seem to be sending `"_utf8":"☃"`, however I haven't looked at the full source code so I could be missing something.

I would try to trim down the example so that your create method calls a route and you expect that route to be called and work from there. You might try removing the whenPOST and replace the expectPOST with `@httpBackend.expectPOST('/api/letters').respond(200)`